# "[Camille Jordan] had a reputation for eccentric choices of notation"

Tags: reference-request, notation, soft-question, math-history

[Camille Jordan's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_Jordan#Biography) mentions that he had a reputation for eccentric choices of notation. This sounds very intriguing ... What are some examples of this?

Comment: I think [hsm.SE (history of science and mathematics)](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for this sort of question.